# Something wrong with package view style in Eclipse/STS for MacOS

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

[image]
As shown in the picture, the blank packages are shown in different branches respectively, while the packages under /src/test/java look normal.

Why?

I have tried to delete the workspace setting files and also those files under project's directory. But it is still wrong and so confusing.

The operating system is MacOS.

And there is no hidden file in those directories, seeing this:

[image]

Comment: try to close it and open it again. Or press F5 to refresh.

Comment: @Desert As I said, I even delete the whole workspace and reload those codes.

Comment: oh sorry then. I didn't read that.

Comment: Click the upside-down triangle in the corner of the view and change the package layout.

Comment: @nitind it failed, I've already switched to the hierarchical mode (as shown in the picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have hidden files in the intermediate packages which are stopping the collapse. On macOS files starting with '.' are considered hidden.

In the view menu (the upside-down triangle menu) change the filtering to show '.* resources' and see if there are any hidden files shown.

On macOS there may be '.DS_Store' files created by macOS Finder - it is safe to delete these.

Comment: I was doubting that and it is not that case. I have updated the problem, see the second image.

Comment: God bless, you r right, dear buddy. I have doubled check each directory with iTerm (ls -al), it is damn right there. :) hahahaha.

Comment: And even we use "shift+command+.", it is still hidden in the finder.